# Rails - Accessing JSON members

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am new to Rails, and working with some JSON, and not sure how to get to the data as the examples below:
1) If i were to use `JSON.parse(response)['Response']['test']['data']['123456']`, i will need to parse another response for `123457`, is there a better way to loop through all the objects in `data`?

2) base on the `membershipId`, identify the top level object, ie `data`.

```
 "test": {
        "data": {
          "123456": {
            "membershipId": "321321312",
            "membershipType": a,
          },
          "123457": {
            "membershipId": "321321312",
            "membershipType": a,

        },
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSON.parse(response)['Response']['test']['data'].each do |key, object|
  puts key 
  puts object['membershipID']
  ...
end
```

To select the data record associated with a particular membership

```
match_membership = '321321312'

member = JSON.parse(response)['Response']['test']['data'].select |_key, object|
  object['membershipID'] == match_membership
end

puts member.key
=> 123456
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

### For 1:

#### Assumption:

By you saying "need to parse another response", you were doing something like below:

```
# bad code: because you are parsing `response` multiple times
JSON.parse(response)['Response']['test']['data']['123456']
JSON.parse(response)['Response']['test']['data']['123457']
```

then simply:

#### Solution 1:

If you are gonna be accessing 2+ level deep hash values for just maybe 2 or 3 times,

```
response_hash = JSON.parse(response)

response_hash['Response']['test']['data']['123456']
response_hash['Response']['test']['data']['123457']
```

#### Solution 2:

If you are gonna be accessing 2+ level deep hash values  for loooooots of times,

```
response_hash = JSON.parse(response)

response_hash_response_test_data = response_hash['Response']['test']['data']

response_hash_response_test_data['123456']
response_hash_response_test_data['123457']
response_hash_response_test_data['123458']
response_hash_response_test_data['123459']
response_hash_response_test_data['123460']
# ...
```

*Solution 2 is better than Solution 1 because it saves repetitive method calls for `Hash#[]` which is the "getter" method each time you do like `...['test']` then `['data']` then `['123456']`, and so is better-off doing Solution 2 which you store the nested-level of the hash into a variable (this does not duplicate the values in-memory!). Plus it's more readable this way.*

Comment: @vincent if you are gonna be looping through each of the `data`, do @SteveTurczyn's solution instead.

Comment: Thanks Jay, will do.